# How to share video on TikTok in iOS?

Tags: swift, video, share

I have local and remote videos. I am implementing video sharing for Instagram, TikTok and other social networks. My application requires support iOS 12+.

For Instagram and TikTok the user should go directly to the selected app with the selected video for sharing from my application.

I am using schemes for Instagram (like `"instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=someIdentifier"`), UIActivityViewController for other social networks.

But I cannot find something for TikTok. I did not find any API for that. Also I tried to find some special scheme.

May be someone knows that is it possible or not?

---

UPD.

Tik Tok released [iOS SDK](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/ios-quickstart).

Unfortunately, my watermarked videos are not allowed for sharing.

Comment: Did you found the solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But on the weekend I will try to find ipa file of Tik Tok. May be it will help to find some schemes.

Comment: Why do you say "watermarked videos are not allowed", is there any doc for this rule?

Comment: @TommyChang Hi, the doc has a note: "Videos with brand logo or watermark will lead to the videos being deleted or the respective accounts disabled. Make sure your application shares content without a watermark."

https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/video-kit-ios-video-kit-with-swift

Comment: Ok, I see. . thanks. Finally, which solution are you using?

Comment: My answer is below. I used the scheme `snssdk1233://` to open Tik Tok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official answer is to use the SDK for iOS and Android: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc

Comment: Thanks. They released SDK about a month ago, I did not know that.
 
Unfortunately, watermarked videos are not allowed.

Comment: Is there a Swift version of this?

Comment: Can someone post an example of how to use the SDK?

Answer (score 7):

My team lead helped me found the only solution.

It is a scheme for opening Tik Tok: `snssdk1233://`. I didn't found something better.

How you could implement it:

1. Save the video to Photo Library.
2. Show a message that the video
   is saved and the user can upload it to Tik Tok.
3. Open Tik Tok:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "snssdk1233://") else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Also there is a scheme `musically://`. It does the same as `snssdk1233://`. (Maybe there is a difference between them)

Comment: can you write an example for sending video request?
please please

Comment: @Negar You should use Tik Tok iOS SDK - https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/ios-quickstart, if there are no watermarks in your videos.

Comment: Thank you! Is it only for opening Tiktok application, not sharing specific file?

Comment: (+ Or opening a view to upload video / capture video, not main list view)

Comment: Sharing does not work.

Only iOS SDK may do it - https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/ios-quickstart

Comment: @VladislavMarkov I have a small error, can you help me?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze what is it?

Comment: @VladislavMarkov have a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68326436/swift-how-to-call-method-to-send-share-request), please

Comment: @LeriGogsadze Unfortunately I don't know Objective-C. I see that you are not passing a completion block to the function, but I don't know the solution.